# Insert into table select where not exists affecting 0 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert into a table with the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table1(
col1, col2, col3)
SELECT distinct
col1, col2, getDate()
FROM table2 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM table1, table2
    WHERE ((table1.col1 = table2.col1) or (table1.col1 is null and table2.col1 is null))
    AND ((table1.col2 = table2.col2) or (table1.col2 is null and table2.col2 is null)))
```

But when I run the query, it shows (0 row(s) affected).

The SELECT statement within the NOT EXISTS statement returns the correct number of rows that I don't want inserted. If I try to insert into the table without the WHERE NOT EXISTS statement, it inserts everything. I only want to insert rows that are not already in table1.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide some sample data from `table1` and `table2`, and the rows from `table2` that you expect to be inserted. (Your `NOT EXISTS` query is horrific, but it's hard to suggest a specific way to improve it without some sample data to use to do so.)

Comment: To understand what `Exists` does just try `Select * from TableX where not Exists(Select 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optimize this query quite a bit, but as a quick fix you could change:

```
SELECT 1 FROM table1, table2
```

to:

```
SELECT 1 FROM table1
```

This will tie the outer table2 into your subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table1(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT distinct col1, col2, getDate()
FROM table2 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM table1
    WHERE ((table1.col1 = table2.col1) or (table1.col1 is null and table2.col1 is null))
    AND ((table1.col2 = table2.col2) or (table1.col2 is null and table2.col2 is null)))
```

Comment: Holy crap. I think that did it! Could you explain why this works and not what I had?

Comment: Hi, if you use a Table2 in the sub query it isn't the same of the main query, but a copy. Instead, if you use Table2 of main query you link the two tables so the result is correct.